# array_intersect() with dynamic length of arguments

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic

I've got an array of arrays that may have a different count of elements when the script is run.

```
$strict = [
    [0] => ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'],
    [1] => ['one', 'two', 'four', 'eight'],
    [2] => ['two', 'four', 'ten', 'twenty'],
 /* [x] => [. . .] */
];

$result = array_intersect($strict[0], $strict[1], $strict[2]);
print_r($result); //shows ['two', 'four'];
```

I want to do something like this though:

```
$result = array_intersect($strict);
```

Where I pass in a dynamic length array of arrays and `array_intersect` will go through each one and take only the common entries.

Doing `array_intersect($strict)` does not work, because the function requires at least two arguments.

Maybe something like

```
array_intersect(function ($array) {
    $list = '';
    foreach ($array as $el) {
        $list .= $el.',';
    }

    $list = rtrim($list, ',');

    return eval($list);
});
```

though this particular method still throws the error

> Warning: array_intersect(): at least 2 parameters are required, 1
>   given

Comment: Are you looking to get a list of all the elements in `$strict[0]` that occur in any of the other elements in `$strict`?

Comment: If you use Mark Baker's solution and use the splat operator then you can call array_intersect without the warning being thrown so long as there is at least one array of arrays in $strict.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php):

> Call a callback with an array of parameters

So your callback would be `array_intersect`, and you could pass your array like this:

```
$result = call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $strict);
```

Comment: It's working for me while 3 dots not working ( it's a better option to use instead of array_intersect(...$strict);  ). 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You can take advantage of modern PHP's array packing/unpacking features - aka variadics, or the so-called "splat" (`...`) operator - as well:

```
$result = array_intersect(...$strict);
```